# How to log out of PIXEL

Tags: retropie, pixel

I just installed RetroPi in Raspbian and now the install manual for RetroPi (https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Manual-Installation/) says I need to log out of PIXEL to use RetroPi. How can I do this? I have searched google and can't find anything that says how. Thanks in advance!

Comment: PIXEL is the name of the Raspbian Desktop (As far as I understand). At what step exactly in the tutorial does the error message occur?

Comment: The very last part. When I type in `emulationstation` its spits out errors and when I look them up I found a post on the RetroPi forums saying you need to log out of PIXEL.

Comment: Yes you have to type that command after you log out. Try CTRL+ALT+F1 to open the 'virtual terminal' and then type `logout`. Then try to run emulationstation.

Comment: I think Camp bell is correct.   There maybe a problem in that this takes you back to the GUI login, which is not what you want.  You probably need to shut PIXEL down and start `emulationstation` from the console (i.e., without any GUI running).  Can't say for sure tho as I'm not user.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you have the money, buy a dedicated RetroPi SD (32GB ~$10).

Set Raspbian to boot CLI (command Line Interface); top-left pi icon->Preferences->"Raspberry Pi Configuration" -> "System" Tab->Boot: "To CLI".

reboot

and when you want to run PIXEL Desktop again use the startx command.
"Shutdown..." menu will change to "Exit to command line"